# Clicking on verification email getting error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Once submittied the form sending an email with verification link to user clicking on that link getting 500 internal server error.Once i click on the link status is to changed to 1 from 0  and need to set the time limit for the link 
Error:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Here is my code for email verification.

Signup:

```
function signup()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|is_unique[profile_details.email]');

    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
   {    
    $data['country'] = $this->signup_model->getcountry();  
    $data['mainpage']='signup';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
else
    {
        $data=array(            

      'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),

       );

       if($this->signup_model->insertprofiledetails($data))
           {
                if ($this->signup_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email')))
                {
                    redirect("index.php/welcome/add");
                }
                else
                {
                    redirect("index.php/welcome/add");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('index.php/welcome/add');
            }
        }
    }

function verify($hash=NULL)
{
    if ($this->signup_model->verifyEmailID($hash))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your Email Address is successfully verified! Please login to access your account!</div>');
        redirect('index.php/welcome/add');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Sorry! There is error verifying your Email Address!</div>');
        redirect('index.php/welcome/add');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function sendEmail($to_email)
{

    //configure email settings
    $config=Array(
    'protocol'=> 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //smtp host name
    'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
    'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'yyyyy', //$from_email password
    'mailtype' =>'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    //send mail
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Admin');
    $this->email->to('yyyyy@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email Verification');
    $this->email->message('Dear User,<br /><br />Please click on the below activation link to verify your email address.<br /><br /> http://qa.domain.in/index.php/welcome/verify/' . md5($to_email) . '<br /><br /><br />Thanks<br />Mydomain Team');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    if($this->email->send())
    { 
     redirect('welcome/add');
    } else { echo $this->email->print_debugger(); }
}

function verifyEmailID($key)
{
    $data = array('status' => 1);
    $this->db->where('md5(email)', $key);
    return $this->db->update('profile_details', $data);
}
```

Comment: anyone can help this thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use `redirect` function without `index.php`, like this `redirect("welcome/add");`

Comment: @AlexanderPopov if i click on the link then i am getting this error as internal server error

Comment: @AlexanderPopov removed index.php file getting this error. Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: As I understand from your question this code is executed `$this->signup_model->verifyEmailID($hash)` and status of email is updated, correct?

Comment: @AlexanderPopov yes data is inserting correctly and email is working fine but when i click on the click getting this error

Comment: May I see your routes file's related part?

Comment: @AlexanderPopov when i click on the click it is getting error and email  status is not updating.

Comment: @DenizB. i am not getting what you are saying

Comment: Please open application/config/routes.php and copy the content here.

Comment: @DenizB. In root folder i am having only this $route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: And also please open application/config/config.php and change log_threshold value to 4. After that try to verify your email again. Than you should see a log file under application/logs. Please copy that file's content too.

Comment: OK. I think reason is not routes but you better use routes. Please add this line in your routes file:

`$route['welcome/verify/(:any)'] = 'Welcome/verify/$1';`

Comment: @DenizB. just got the mail but i didnt get any verication mail in that

Comment: Did you make the log thing?

Comment: @DenizB. added that line route file but i am getting only email not any verification link in that mail

Comment: Please do the logs thing too, so we can see the error logs and debug.

Comment: @DenizB. yes i changed the log file $config['log_threshold'] = 4;

Comment: But in the log folder nothing is present in that

Comment: OK, now try validation again. Than check application/logs folder. There should be a file in it.

Comment: Wait, you're redirecting users to "welcome/add", is there any function called "add" under Welcome class?

Comment: In application -logs folder only index.html file is there nothing is present in that.Yes function add is for signup it is there in welcome controller

Comment: @DenizB. getting this error Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Is there any function called "add" under Welcome class? If it is not, of course you will get 404.

Comment: Welcome is a controller in that i am having a function add

Comment: @DenizB. getting the same error but in the logs folder nothing is displaying.

Comment: :) Welcome is a Class in your Controller file. If you can't find a solution please let me know, I need to leave now.

Comment: My controller name is welcome in that add is a function method

Comment: @DenizB. my problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are missing any closing brackets for any methods in the signup_model class or the sign_up model class itself or for the controller

Comment: Everything is fine i have checked closed brackets and all

Comment: Have you loaded the signup_model in controller?

Comment: yes i have loaded signup_model it is inserting data in database as well as i am getting mail but the problem is when i click on the link getting error.

Comment: Did you use the correct domain name? in the link? ` http://qa.domain.in/index.php/welcome/verify/' . md5($to_email)`

Comment: my domain name is qa.domain.in

Comment: Then it seems the problem might be to do with routing. Maybe [this](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html) might help

Comment: If it is problem with routing then everything is working correct right except mail verification